# how to suppress btrfs startup scan

Tags: startup, btrfs

on my system is **btrfs** only needed for some external disks. So I do not need and do not want a startup delay about 15s for a scan at startup.

Does someone know how to tell the ubuntu startup scrippts not to check for that filesystem at startup. I found in here some people does purge than the btrfs but this is for me no solution as I want tu use the mudule sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following answer:

modify the file `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-premount/btrfs`

I did only insert a `#` in the line where the btrfs scan is called.

than did the following commands:

`update-initramfs -uk all`

`grub-install`

now the module gets loaded but the scan is suppressed while startup.

`update-grub`